# How do kernel inform OSPF daemon when a physical interface status is down?

Tags: networking, kernel, process

When a physical interface status is changed from up to down, there are 3 things related to the computer's current routing table and OSPF.

1. The (connected) network for that interface and remote networks that are routed via that (connected) network are removed from the computer's routing table.
2. OSPF neighbors on that (connected) network are removed from the OSPF's neighbors table.
3. Remote networks that are routed via that (connected) network are removed from the OSPF's routing table.

My question is how do the kernel inform OSPF daemon when a physical interface status is down? It seems like it is a mandatory for the kernel to keep informing the OSPF daemon some information like physical interface status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on operating system -- via routing socket (BSD family) or netlink socket (Linux).  Very brief overview of available kernel interfaces is in [GNU Quagga's documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/docs/docs-multi/Kernel-Interface.html#Kernel-Interface).

Answer (score 0):

I think this question wont arise where link state is learned from ospf routers through Dead interval within which routers need to send hello packets in order to maintain their status up, otherwise the link is treated as down. OSPFD cannot communicate to neighbours or adjacencies when its ethernet link is down.